# Unable to extract data which is compressed as per IETF RFC 1951: "DEFLATE Compressed Data Format Specification version 1.3"

Tags: c, compression, zlib

I want to decompress data which is (or supposed to be as per the specification I'm referring to) in DEFLATE compression format as specified in RFC 1951. Im using zlib library in C. 
I referred to this example in github : 
https://gist.github.com/gaurav1981/9f8d9bb7542b22f575df

And modified it just to decompress my data:

```
    char dData[MAX_LENGTH];
    char cData[MAX_LENGTH]; 

    for(i=0; i < (size-4); i++)
    {
        cData[i] = *(data + i);
    }
    //cData[i] = '\0';
    printf("Compressed size is: %lu\n", strlen(cData));

    z_stream infstream;
    infstream.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    infstream.zfree = Z_NULL;
    infstream.opaque = Z_NULL;
    // setup "b" as the input and "c" as the compressed output
    //infstream.avail_in = (uInt)((char*)defstream.next_out - b); // size of input
    //infstream.avail_in = (uInt)((char*)defstream.next_out - cData);
    infstream.avail_in = (uInt)(size - 4);
    infstream.next_in = (Bytef *)cData; // input char array
    infstream.avail_out = (uInt)sizeof(dData); // size of output
    infstream.next_out = (Bytef *)dData; // output char array

    // the actual DE-compression work.
    inflateInit(&infstream);
    inflate(&infstream, Z_NO_FLUSH);
    inflateEnd(&infstream);

    printf("Uncompressed size is: %lu\n", strlen(dData));

    size = strlen(dData);
```

My uncompressed size is 0. So can someone tell what's wrong with my code?

I even wrote the data into a file and saved it as .gz and .zip but an error came when i tried to extract it (I'm running ubuntu 14.04)

And can someone be kind enough to analyse my data and extract it if it is possible. My data :

```
6374 492d 2d29 4ece c849 cc4b
294a 4cc9 cc57 f02e cd29 292d 6292 7780
30f2 1293 338a 3293 334a 52f3 98c4 0b9c
4a93 33b2 8b32 4b32 b399 d405 4212 d353
8b4b 320b 0a00
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `inflate()`, you need to call `inflateInit2()` with the second argument being `-15`, in order to decompress raw deflate data.

Answer (score 0):

Your data starts with \0, so strlen will return 0, that you have print as length of uncompressed data

Comment: Sorry this is my data 6374 492d 2d29 4ece c849 cc4b 294a 4cc9
cc57 f02e cd29 292d 6292 7780 30f2 1293
338a 3293 334a 52f3 98c4 0b9c 4a93 33b2
8b32 4b32 b399 d405 4212 d353 8b4b 320b
0a00